# Joining 2 tables where table2 contains multiple rows for each table1 row

Tags: sql, join

Either I'm over-thinking this or my SQL skills are lacking. I need to add two columns to a table from a second table, but the values are in separate rows in the second table. What SQL would do this? Here's an example. *transnum* is the common column between the tables.

```
TABLE1
------
transnum  id
9287      006
5782      004
5819      001

TABLE2
------
transnum  code  value
9287      A     198.38
9287      B     928.57
9287      C     568.25  -- code C values not needed
5782      A     219.53
5782      B     591.11
5782      C     852.32
5819      A     109.92
5819      B     251.81
5819      C     295.12

DESIRED RESULT
--------------
transnum  id    valueA  valueB
9287      006   198.38  928.57
5782      004   219.53  591.11
5819      001   109.92  251.81
```

EDIT: Grammar.

Comment: Wish I could give 'best answer' to both Joel and Neo. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join to the same table twice with different criteria:

```
SELECT t1.TransNum, t1.id, t2_A.value "ValueA", t2_B.value "ValueB"
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2_A ON t2_A.transnum = t1.transnum AND t2_A.code = 'A'
INNER JOIN Table2 t2_B ON t2_B.transnum = t1.transnum AND t2_B.code = 'B'
```

Depending on what you're doing, you may need to use `LEFT JOIN`s instead of `INNER JOIN`s, if there are situations where there may only be data for one of the codes. If you do that, you may also want to use the `COALESCE()` function on the values in the select clause to show something other than `NULL` when there is no matching record.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to `JOIN` to the table twice, with a very finite filter:

```
SELECT t1.transum, t1.id, t2.value AS valueA, t3.value AS valueB
FROM table1 t1
    JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.transum = t1.transum AND t2.code = 'A'
    JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.transum = t1.transum AND t3.code = 'B'
```